# undefined method `line_items_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

I'm newbie to Rails.

This is my **LineItems Controller**

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController

def create
    @cart=current_cart
    product=Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item=@cart.line_items.build(:product=>product)
    if @line_item.save
        redirect_to @line_item.cart
        flash.now[:success]="Added to Cart"
    else
        render :action=>'new'
    end
end 
end
```

In one of my views i added a button for **Add to Cart**

```
<%= button_to "Add to Cart" , line_items_path(product_id: product), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

But that is giving me **NoMethodError**

> undefined method `line_items_path'

What's the error? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Figured it out. Needed to add a route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the resource to your routes file:

config/routes.rb

```
resources :list_items
```